# How to import cordova.js with Parcel

Tags: vue.js, cordova, mobile, parceljs

I'm trying to use Vue and Parcel along with Cordova.

But importing Cordova like `import cordova from "cordova";` doesn't seem to work, and adding it as a script throws an error because it can't reference it.

My script looks like this in order to create the www folder `parcel watch src/index.html --out-dir www --public-url /CordovaVue/app-cordova-vue/www` should I run something else beforehand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should add the cordova script dynamically. Like this:

```
// Dynamically load cordova
var cordova = document.createElement('script')
cordova.setAttribute('type','text/javascript')
cordova.setAttribute('src', 'cordova.js')
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(cordova)
```

Source: https://github.com/Viglino/parcel-cordova/blob/master/index.js